# C++ equality check on char from cin against another char never equates to true??? (No compiler errors)

Tags: c++, if-statement, equality, cin

I'm stuck as to why the condition below isn't triggering when either an 'n' or a 'y' is entered at the console. When executed you can't get out the the if statement, but i know for sure that

```
!(cin >> again)
```

isn't the culprit, as that was previously the only condition in the if statement and I was able to skip/enter the if block if a character/numeral was entered, which was as expected. Here is the code:

```
char again;

while (1) {
  cout << endl;
  cout << "I see another one, care to shoot again? (y/n): ";

  if (!(cin >> again) || (again != 'n') || (again != 'y')) {
    // Error checking for numberals & non 'y' or 'n' characters
    cout << "Please enter 'y' or 'n' only." << endl;
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(1000, '\n');
    continue;
  }
  break;
}
```

I'm stumped on this so any help would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: Replace both `||` with `&&`

Comment: Why don't you answer instead of comment?

Comment: For which value of `again` is `(again != 'n') || (again != 'y')` false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(...|| (again != 'n') || (again != 'y')) {
```

is faulty logic. What you say is

> if "again" is not n or it's not y, then do the following...

now, since "again" can't be n and y at the same time, this always evaluates to `true`; most probably, even your compiler notices that and just jumps right into your `if`'s content.

What you want is something like

```
 if(!(cin>>again) || ( again != 'n' && again != 'y') {
```

Because that reads

> if `cin>>again` didn't work or `again` is neither `n` nor `y` then,...

Comment: Oh gawdd, I feel really silly now. I don't even have the run the code with the amendment to realise thats the issue. Thank you for the quick response! I'm marking the question as answered as soon as i can!